# Creating tags between markdown files similar to :h

Tags: filesystem, tags

One of the first things you learn in vimtutor is to follow links in the vim help files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>. I'm interested in creating my own tags/linking system in arbitrary files. For the sake of this question, let's say I'm creating a sort of TODO list in markdown.

Suppose that we have the following minifile:

```
TODO
=====
  1. Learn Vimscript the Hard Way    |hardway|

(some other things, maybe)


Complete Learn Vimscript the Hard Way
-------------------------------------  :hardway

(Some sort of details, etc.)
```

Then the goal would be to put the cursor on the first `|hardway|`, hit something akin to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>, and be transported to the `:hardway` tag located elsewhere. Ideally, this could even occur if `:hardway` was in a different file (but maybe the same directory).

I currently use a low-tech alternative. Instead of `|hardway|`, I would have something like `|hardway.md|`, so that I can <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> on the "tag" and ge taken to the `hardway.md` file. While this is manageable, I feel like it should be possible (maybe even not hard) to create and maintain my own tag system on arbitrary filetypes.

Comment: Take a look at ‘:h write-help`

Comment: Sorry :h help-writing

Comment: @LeonardoConstantino Unless I'm mistaken, this would be akin to literally integrating my todo list into vim's help system. I'm not interested in typing `:h hardway` and being taken to my entry on `hardway` which is actually a helpfile. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion? Forgive me, I'm not entirely certain.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented something like this using [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and a `.ctags` file
in the directory (should also work with `.ctags` in the home directory).

You can read up on using Ctags with arbitrary regex, but the gist of it is that you'll
be able to use that same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-`]` to go to these tags.

The contents of my `.ctags`:

```
--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.md
--regex-markdown=/^#+\s*([^#]*)\s*#+$/\1/h,heading,headings/
```

Then run ctags.

```
ctags -R
```

And you should get a file called `tags` which has mappings for all markdown headers
in the `### HEADER ###` format.

See [`:help tags`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tagsrch.txt) for more information about navigating tags (e.g. when there are
multiple hits for a tag).

Comment: ctags approach asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742396/creating-ctags-extension-for-markdown

Answer (score 1):

VIM's `:find` and `gf` are quite awesome, I use them all the time, they rely on the vim setting `path` and look for files in there. VIM also provides additional setting `suffixesadd` which is a list of suffixes find will try to add to the file names and look them up. eg.) `set suffixesadd+='.md'` to work with markdown files.